# .htaccess redirection to tidy URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

This is what my **.htaccess** file looks like:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

#removes trailing slash if not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#adds ".php" to a URL that isn't a directory or a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Although it lets me access the url without the .php in the end for e.g. `example.com/sign-up`
It does not redirect me from `example.com/sign-up.php` to `example.com/sign-up`

Is there any code which I can add to this file to make that happen?

Any insight would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot answer this in comments so posting this as an answer:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove PHP from root level requests 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.php$ /$1 [R=302,NE,L,NC]

# To internally redirect /foo to /foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This :

```
RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Wow! This is awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Also how do I redirect from: http://example.com/?slug=hey-there

to: http://example.com/hey-there

Please help @ansuman-chauhan

Comment: Is there any way through which I can limit this redirection only to root level for e.g.: example.com/sing.php should redirect to example.com/sing

but that should not happen with example.com/data/sync.php..

Any ideas @anubhava

Thanks for your time!